# Proof on inductive sets

Tags: set, isabelle, induction

I am trying to wrap my brain around proofs on inductive sets and I am failing miserably.
This is what I have so far:

```
theory MyTheory

imports Main
begin

inductive_set S where
  emptyI: "{} ∈ S" | 
  insertI: "A ∈ S ⟹ insert a A ∈ S"

definition plus :: "'a set set ⇒ 'a set set ⇒ 'a set set" (infixl "❙+" 100) where 
  "a ❙+ b = a ∪ b"
definition zero :: "'a set set" ("❙0") where 
  "❙0 = {}"

locale myLocale = 
  fixes f :: "'a set set ⇒ 'a set set"
  assumes f_zero: "f ❙0 = ❙0"
      and f_plus: "f (a ∪ b) = f a ∪ f b"
      and a_fin: "⋀a::'a set set. finite a"
begin

lemma 
  assumes "a ∈ S" "a = ⋃{{x}| x. x ∈ a}" "finite a"
  shows "f a = ⋃{f {x}| x. x ∈ a}"
proof cases 
case emptyI
  show ?thesis sorry
next
case (insertI A a)
  show ?thesis sorry
qed
end
```

I don't understand how to use the S.cases or S.induct in the proof, as described in Mr. Ballarin's example in [Inductive Definitions](https://www21.in.tum.de/%7Eballarin/belgrade08-tut/session06/session06.pdf) (Slide 22).

With `proof cases` (or `proof induct`), my example definitely doesn't work:

```
Proof outline with cases:
  case True
  then show ?thesis sorry
next
  case False
  then show ?thesis sorry
qed
```

What am I missing?

LE: Oooh... I figured it out (digging more around for Mr. Ballarin's Demos on that tutorial!)
What I was missing was the "anchoring" of the induction to the assumption `"a ∈ S"`. Fixed it and all is well in my world now.

```
lemma 
  assumes **a0:** "a ∈ S" "a = ⋃{{x}| x. x ∈ a}" "finite a"
  shows "f a = ⋃{f {x}| x. x ∈ a}"
  **using a0**
proof cases 
case emptyI
  show ?thesis sorry
next
case (insertI A a)
  show ?thesis sorry
qed
```